# How do I select only 1 specific dom element that has no class or ID AFTER another specific one?

Tags: css

This is what my HTML looks like (fun...I know):

```
<p itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemprop="address" class="adr">
  <span itemprop="streetAddress" class="street-address">6306 N Cicero Ave</span>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality" class="locality">Chicago,&nbsp;</span>
  <span itemprop="addressRegion">IL</span>&nbsp;
  <span itemprop="postalCode">60646</span>
</p>
```

What I want to select individually are the state span and the zipcode span...aka

```
<span itemprop="addressRegion">IL</span>
```

And

```
<span itemprop="postalCode">60646</span>
```

Given that the span right before it has a class:

```
<span itemprop="addressLocality" class="locality">Chicago,&nbsp;</span>
```

And the ones I am interested in have neither a `class` or an `id`, how do I select both of those individually?

Comment: `span[itemprop="addressRegion"] {...}` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Bingo. This works. Thanks much. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
span[itemprop="addressRegion"], span[itemprop="postalCode"] { 
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the attribute property.

https://jsfiddle.net/25euucb0/

```
[itemprop~=addressRegion] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}

[itemprop~=postalCode] {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: the ~ selector is to address if he wants them all

Comment: For some reason, the parser is choking on using this attribute property. For what it's worth, I am not doing normal CSS selecting. I am using an HTML parser in Ruby that is parsing the HTML and I am selecting from there. So it is possible that the lexer doesn't know of/like this way of selecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the (+) selector, it finds next sibling element.

EDIT: Just used the (~) siblings selector, check it out.

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/4xzyva6L/

HTML

```
<p itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemprop="address" class="adr">
  <span itemprop="streetAddress" class="street-address">6306 N Cicero Ave</span>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality" class="locality">Chicago,&nbsp;</span>
  <span itemprop="addressRegion">IL</span>&nbsp;
  <span itemprop="postalCode">60646</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.locality ~ span{
    background-color:lime;
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that `.locality+span` works for me...but `.locality+span+span` doesn't. So this answer is half-way there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you checked the snippet? The (+) finds the adjacent sibling, what browser are you working on?

Comment: I did check the snippet. I see that it works for you, but not sure why it doesn't work in my project. I am using Chrome on OS X.

Comment: EDIT: Just used the (~) siblings selector, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Use CSS pseudo-class **[:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)**

Put the attribute selector as argument in *`not()`* selector something like **`span:not([atttribute])`**

```
 .adr span:not([class]){
    background-color:yellow;
  }

.adr span:not([class])+span{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Check [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hidaytrahman/2ypqfsn3/)